# select from first row to secord row in database

Tags: javascript, sql

I am making a project where I need dates from a database.
when a certain date has passed, the second row needs to come in that place and so on.

I don't really know how to do this, so hopefully, someone could help me

I noticed that this didn't work

```
 function Load() {
        var sql = "SELECT TijdVan, ID_RECORD FROM pixiocompanys WHERE TijdVan >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY TijdTot" ;

        var result = sqlUtil.selectSql(sql, {} , 'default');

            if (result.length === 0 ){
                return;
            }
                var times = getTimes(); 
                var d = new Date();
                var TV = times[0].TijdVan;
                var TT = times[0].TijdTot;
            if( d > TV ){

                var sql = "SELECT TijdVan , ID_RECORD FROM pixiocompanys" ;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, if you just want to get the row with the next closest date, you can use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT 
  TijdVan, 
  ID_RECORD 
FROM pixiocompanys 
WHERE TijdVan >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
ORDER BY TijdTot
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: OK, see updated response.  Are you looking to just get a single row with the next closest date?

Comment: am indeed looking for  the next closest date (of 1), (so thats 2) when that date is active, its running a script, when that date is no longer relevant , it needs to search again (date 3) and so on

Comment: I don't quite follow.  Are you saying you want to continually call the Load() function? How do you determine if a date is active?  I'd think that logic would go in your JS function.